# Unity key input control statement incorrect

Tags: unity-game-engine

This the script I use for the movement of my Endless Runner game made in Unity3D 5.1.2f1 Personal. Moving to the right works completely. Moving the left doesn't work, but the debug.log does work. In the inspector I can see the 'leftrightSpeed' is set to 2 when moving to the right but nothing happens to the float when moving to the left. What am I doing wrong here?

(Float speed is set to 5 in the inspector).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float leftrightSpeed;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //LEFT
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            leftrightSpeed = -2f;
            Debug.Log ("LEFT");
        }
        else
        {
            leftrightSpeed = 0f;
        }

         //RIGHT
        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            leftrightSpeed = 2f;
            Debug.Log ("RIGHT");
        }
        else
        {
            leftrightSpeed = 0f;
        }

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (-2f, 0.0f, leftrightSpeed);

    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not be using FixedUpdate.  google a million pages on this.  it's a great pity Unity ever mentioned it in the manual.

Comment: There are no chatty question headlines on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerry is correct it is your 2nd if statment that cancels out your Left movement. You could improve your `FixedUpdate` method by simply using `GetAxis` like so:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    leftrightSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 2;
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (-2f, 0.0f, leftrightSpeed);
    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
```

Essentially GetAxis will give a number between -1 and 1 depending on which key is being pressed in correlation to the "horizonal" axis. This will work for game controllers, arrow keys, or even the w/a/s/d movement by default.

Check out the documentation for [GetAxis](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `leftrightSpeed` to 0 in else block of second condition when you press anything else then right key. That is why it works for right. That is it.

To do it right, change it to

```
if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        leftrightSpeed = 2f;
        Debug.Log ("RIGHT");
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        leftrightSpeed = -2f;
        Debug.Log ("LEFT");
    }       
    else
    {
        leftrightSpeed = 0f;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I see it now! Thank you so much!!

Comment: hi @BelgianWizard . as a new user you need to TICK and answer.

Comment: FTR you can't really get keystrokes this way, consider if both are being touched.  Also nobody should ever use "else-if".

Comment: @JoeBlow Nobody should ever use "else-if" ? Please, why?